# C++ executable fails to link to shared library after scp

Tags: linux, cmake, centos, shared-libraries

So I am working on a project that is intended to run on a remote server. I develop the program on a local pc, compile it, then upload it to the remote server. Both the local pc and the remote server are run on CentOS 7.7.

The program is developed using the CLion IDE, configured with CMake. The program depends a few shared libraries, which are supposed to link to the executable according to what I wrote in CMake. At my local PC, I can compile and run the program perfectly. However, after I `scp` the whole directory of the project to the remote server, the executable fails to run. It cannot find any of the ".so" files, according to what `ldd` says.

This is my CMakeList.txt, with every path being relative path, instead of absolute path.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(YS_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_PATH_ src)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES_ ${SOURCE_PATH_}/*.*)

set(PROJECT_LIBS_ libTapQuoteAPI.so libTapTradeAPI.so libTapDataCollectAPI.so)

include_directories(api/include)
link_directories(api/lib/linux)

add_executable(YS_Test ${SOURCE_FILES_})

target_link_libraries(YS_Test ${PROJECT_LIBS_})
```

Please do not tell me to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to fix my issue. The program worked fine on my local pc without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I expect it to run on the remote server without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I would like to know what is really going on here, instead of a work around. Thanks!

Comment: When build the executable, CMake by default embeds into it the absolute paths to the libraries as RPATH. If paths to your libraries are changed after scp, then you need to manually control RPATH, and CMake provides ways for that: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. (That help could be more detailed would you add more details into your question. E.g. exact error message, exact locations of the executable and libraries on your PC and after `scp` and so on).

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been downvoted. The OP wants to know how the Linux dynamic linker works when trying to resolve dependencies. It would also be nice to tag the question with 'centos' or 'linux', but there are only 5 tags available per question!

Comment: @Pedro Here we go ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to ship your compiled `YS_Test` program along with some dependencies and have it run on a remote server. By default an executable will only look in the directories configured in `/etc/ld.so`, which will not include the deploy path.

Note: Typically you do not deploy your *entire build directory* but only the compiled artifacts and dependencies. For this answer I will assume you deploy the binary and its dependencies to the **same** directory.

You have two options:

- Require users of your program to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, either by themselves or by a wrapper script. This variable will instruct the dynamic linker to look in the specified directories as well. Even if you do not like this solution, it is by far the most common approach.
- Add `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'` to your linker options.  This will add a `DT_RUNPATH` attribute to the executable's dynamic section. As you are using CMake you can also set this using `BUILD_RPATH` and/or `INSTALL_RPATH` target properties.
  The ld.so manpage describes this attribute as follows:

  > If  a  shared  object  dependency  does not contain a slash, then it is
  >      searched for in the following order:
  >
  > - ...
  > - Using the directories specified in the  DT_RUNPATH  dynamic  section
  >       attribute of the binary if present.

  The `$ORIGIN` part expands to the directory containing the program  or  shared
            object.

If you **really** insist on shipping your build directory (eg during development), you can take a look at the CMake [`BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/prop_tgt/BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN.html#prop_tgt:BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN) property (and its usual global counterpart CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH_USE_ORIGIN), this will embed *relative* paths into binaries instead of absolute paths.

Comment: Wonderful answer! However, if I can manipulate the library paths with LD_LIBRARY_PATH after compilation, what is the point of setting paths in CMakeList.txt.

Comment: Presumably (I have not tested this) telling CMake to set relative RPATHs in the executable would allow you to just ship your build directory, as you asked. Other than that, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not always an option (if you're providing a library that loads other libraries, for example)

Comment: If an answer helped you with your problem, please mark it as accepted so other people can find it.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't want a workaround (@Botje has given you two already), I will try an explanation instead. In your development machine, if you use this command:

```
ldd YS_Test
```

You will see all the shared libraries used by your program, with their corresponding paths. The libTapQuoteAPI.so libTapTradeAPI.so libTapDataCollectAPI.so are found at your 'api/lib/linux' directory, but resolved with full absolute paths. If you do the same at your server, some  shared objects can't be resolved because they aren't at the same location.

If you use one of these commands (not sure which are available in Centos):

```
chrpath --list YS_Test
```

or

```
patchelf --print-rpath YS_Test
```

You will see the `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` tags embedded in your program. This is the path used by the Linux linker to locate dependencies that are outside the standard `ld` locations. You may find extended explanations on Internet about this, like [this one](https://flameeyes.blog/2010/06/20/the-why-and-how-of-rpath/) or [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

Breaking my promise, I give you a third workaround: use `patchelf` or `chrpath` at your server after `scp` to change the embedded `RPATH` tag, pointing it relative to `$ORIGIN` (which represents the program location).

Comment: Good writeup! Two comments: you can use `readelf -d` to read dynamic section attributes (such as `DT_RUNPATH`), and `chrpath` refuses to add a runpath if the executable/library does not already have it.